Power BI - Tree chart out of only numerical data
In my data model I have a table with data that approximately looks like this:



ID
Cash_All_Accounts
Cash_Current_Accounts
Cash_Saving_Accounts
Cash_Long_Term_Saving_Accounts
Cash_Short_Term_Saving_Accounts




1
100
50
50
25
25


2
200
50
150
100
50



The columns 'Cash_Current_Accounts' and 'Cash_Saving_Accounts' are subsets of the 'Cash_All_Accounts' column. Additionally, the columns 'Cash_Long_Term_Saving_Accounts' and 'Cash_Short_Term_Saving_Accounts' are subsets of the 'Cash_Saving_Accounts' column.
So in other words these two equations are always true:

Cash_All_Accounts = Cash_Current_Accounts + Cash_Saving_Accounts
Cash_Saving_Accounts = Cash_Long_Term_Saving_Accounts + Cash_Short_Term_Saving_Accounts

I want to create a tree chart in power bi that will looks like this:

Is it possible to get something like this using built-in power bi tree chart or some custom chart?

You should be able to use the decomposition tree.  First you have to normalise your data, so your input table could like like for example:
ID | Current | Savings  | Amount
---|---------|----------|-------
 1 | Cash    |          | 50
 1 | Savings | Long  t  | 25
 1 | Savings | Short t  | 25

and next just set up the decomposition tree visual:

This article has more info about this particular visual.
